# ExecuteNonQuery() returns -1 in Update when records are updated

Tags: c#, asp.net, oracle11g

I've verified that my method/Oracle procedure is working correctly, but in my C# I always get -1 returned from ExecuteNonQuery().  Consequently, the below bool is always false.  We only use Triggers in our DB (Oracle) for INSERT statements.  Do I need a trigger for an update statement?

Any suggestions why that would happen?  Its definitely updating one record:

```
public bool ChangePassword(long UserId, string NewPassword)
    {
        int rcds = 0;
        using (OracleConnection dbConn = new OracleConnection(dbConnString))
        using (OracleCommand dbCmd = new OracleCommand("PKG_USER.CHANGE_PASSWORD", dbConn))
        {
            try
            {
                string salt = GenerateSalt();
                dbCmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                dbCmd.Parameters.Add("p_USER_ID", OracleDbType.Int64, UserId, ParameterDirection.Input);
                dbCmd.Parameters.Add("P_PASSWORD", OracleDbType.Varchar2, 128, EncodePassword(NewPassword, this.IsPasswordHashed, salt), ParameterDirection.Input);
                dbCmd.Parameters.Add("P_PASSWORD_SALT", OracleDbType.Varchar2, 128, salt, ParameterDirection.Input);

                if (dbConn.State != ConnectionState.Open) dbConn.Open();
                rcds = dbCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                LastError = e.Message + " " + e.Source;
                rcds = 0;
            }
            finally
            {
                dbCmd.Dispose();
                dbConn.Dispose();
            }
        }
        return (rcds > 0);
    }
```

Sorry... heres the SP:

```
PROCEDURE Change_Password(p_User_Id       IN Users.User_Id%TYPE,
                          p_Password      IN Users.Password%TYPE,
                          p_Password_Salt IN Users.Password_Salt%TYPE) IS


BEGIN
UPDATE Users
   SET Password             = p_Password,
       Password_Salt        = p_Password_Salt,
       Password_Change_Date = SYSDATE
 WHERE User_Id = p_User_Id;

 END Change_Password;
```

Comment: What does your stored proc look like?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

<strike>Try explicitly returning SQL%ROWCOUNT.</strike>

According to MSDN, DbCommand..ExecuteNonQuery will always return -1 for stored procedure calls:

> For UPDATE, INSERT, and DELETE statements, the return value is the number of rows affected by the command. For all other types of statements, the return value is -1.

If I remember correctly from my days of using lots of stored procs, I believe you would need to use an output argument to return stuff like the number of updated rows.

Comment: But shouldn't the ExecuteNonQuery method return the value, rather than an additional output parameter?  That's what it sounds like on MSDN.

Comment: @Barryman9000 - that's not how I read it, and it's not how it works on the SqlCommand either - you're not issuing an UPDATE/INSERT/DELETE command, you're issuing a call to a stored proc - therefore the return value from ExecuteNonQuery is going to be -1. If you want a value other than that, you'll need to return it in a output parameter. (Note that the OracleCommand can also return 0 for a Create/DropTable request: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.oracleclient.oraclecommand.executenonquery.aspx)

Comment: Ah-ha... I was thinking that since I was updating my table, I was issuing and UPDATE command.  Your explaination makes sense though, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not an Oracle guy, but apparently there's a command:

```
set feedback off
```

which prevents it from returning the count of records affected.  Is this line in the stored procedure?  Or have you tried 'set feedback on'?  Functionally I think this is just the reverse of SQL Server's SET NOCOUNT ON/OFF command.