# Integer method always return "-1"?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, razor

I'm very new to ASP.net MVC, I'm trying to build a very basic login form, everything worked fine, I have added the stored procedure for the login method and "added function import", the issue is that it always returns one value "-1" in all cases. let's take a look...

1- MovableAssetsDB.context.cs

```
public virtual int LoginToMovable(string userName, string password)
    {
        var userNameParameter = userName != null ?
            new ObjectParameter("UserName", userName) :
            new ObjectParameter("UserName", typeof(string));

        var passwordParameter = password != null ?
            new ObjectParameter("Password", password) :
            new ObjectParameter("Password", typeof(string));

        return ((IObjectContextAdapter)this).ObjectContext.ExecuteFunction("LoginToMovable", userNameParameter, passwordParameter);
    }
```

2- I made a class called "Data" to handle the method and call the stored procedure

```
public int Login(string username, string password)
    {
        using (var DBcontext = new MovableAssetsEntities())
        {
             int userId = DBcontext.LoginToMovable(username, password);
            return userId;
        }

    }
```

3-In the "Home" view, here is the code of the form and razor code to handle the login process

```
    @{
    Layout = null;
}

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Login";
}



@{ 
    if (IsPost)
    {
        string username = Request.Form["username"];
        string password = Request.Form["password"];

        int userId = new MovableAssets.Classes.Data().Login(username, password);

        if (userId > 0)
        {
            <script>alert("yes");</script>

        }
        else
        {
            <script>alert("No");</script>
        }
    }

}

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Movable Assets</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="@Url.Content("~/Content/Custom/css/style.css")">
</head>

<body>
    <div class="container">
        <p id="home_title">Movable Assets</p>
        <section id="content">
            <form action="#" method="post">
                <h1>Login</h1>
                <div>
                    <input type="text" placeholder="Username" required="" id="username" name="username" />
                </div>
                <div>
                    <input type="password" placeholder="Password" required="" id="password" name="password" />
                </div>
                <div>
                    <input type="submit" value="Log in" />
                </div>
            </form><!-- form -->
        </section><!-- content -->
    </div><!-- container -->
</body>
</html>
```

4-The stored procedure

```
  ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[LoginToMovable]
    @UserName nvarchar(50),
    @Password nvarchar(50)
AS
BEGIN

    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    SELECT ID FROM Utilities.dbo.Users WHERE Utilities.dbo.Users.LogIn = @UserName AND Utilities.dbo.Users.Password = @Password
    AND AppCode = '9'
END
```

Whenever I write down any login credentials I get the value of `userId` to be `-1` any suggestions?!

Comment: Put LoginToMovable SP code here.

Comment: show LoginToMovable code plz

Comment: `ObjectContext.ExecuteFunction` *discards any results returned from the function; and returns the number of rows affected by the execution* (see https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd986915(v=vs.110).aspx). Could that be the cause?

Comment: as you know it is automatically generated by EDM, I didn't write it, is there any alternative code?

Answer (score 4):

The EF model for your stored procedure is returning `-1` because the the default behavior of calling a stored procedure from EF is to return the number of rows modified by its last statement. Since that last statement is a `SELECT`, you get `-1` because `SELECT`s cannot modify rows:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/2203421/1945651

In order to get the values *selected* by your procedure, you need to modify the model:

1. Open the Model Browser for your EF model.
2. Locate the stored procedure under **Function Imports** and double-click it to open its **Edit Function Import** dialog.
3. In the **Returns a Collection Of** box, select **Scalars** and the type that you expect.
4. Click OK, and re-save your EF model.

`DBcontext.LoginToMovable()` should now return a collection of values. After calling it, select the first element from the collection to get the value you want.

Comment: all what you said was already done and i did it again but it's still not working

Comment: @Medo Is it still returning -1? Did you make sure to re-save the model? Can you show us a screenshot of the `Edit Function Import` dialog for that stored procedure?