# OracleCmd.ExecuteNonQuery() returning -1.but the stored procedure is executing successfuly

Tags: .net, oracle, .net-4.7.2, oracle18c

The ExecuteNonQuery() method returning -1 values while executing oracle 18c stored procedure. The stored procedure contains insert and update statements.the insertion and update is happening successfully.

The ExecuteNonQuery should return 1 as the insert/update statements are executing successfully.

Comment: possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2203100/executenonquery-returns-1-in-update-when-records-are-updated

Comment: the result of `ExecuteNonQuery` is not the same thing as the return value of a procedure; you usually need to add a parameter with a direction of return-value

Comment: Thank you all. Could you please clarify me what will be the return value of Executenonquery() in Oracle.ManagedDataAccess .For my stored procedure it was returning -1 but the insertion/update is happening as expected.